# hide the overlay using media queries

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, extjs

when we reduce the browser size to iphone screen a menu button appears.....
when we click the button the overlay appears..........
but the overlay appears when we increase the browser size....
how to hide the over lay....
rajdq0383@gmail.com

http://jsfiddle.net/QYvrt/17/
http://jsfiddle.net/QYvrt/17/embedded/result/

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {

#rightSlider{
    border: 1px solid red;
}

#rightSlider{
            display:none !important;
          }
#rightSlider{ 
            display:inherit !important;
          }

}

#slidenav{
            display:none !important;
          }
#slidenav{ 
            display:inherit !important;
          }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make another media query that say when the width is bigger than x width go to display none

```
@media all and (max-width:300){show overlay}
    @media all and (max-width:1024){hide overlay}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply....http://jsfiddle.net/QYvrt/17/ can you update in the fiddle its confusing

Comment: change the first media query to this one @media (max-width: 307px) :D.